# How to bend a part of sphere or cylinder the incremental way?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to bend a part of a modified sphere that is transformed into an elongated piece of pipe. As you can see in the picture, I have done it by using <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> in order to arrange the bends. But, this is not the best of the way as you can see the rings of vertices are fairly random and do not give any symmetrical increment.

Is there a better way of creating this bend:

a. without getting into modifiers,
b. without any empty object approach?

[image: Bending by free hand]

Comment: thanks! for improving the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Edge Menu > *Bridge Edge Loops* does more than you might think.

[image]

Just the two loops at the ends were selected to be bridged, here. You could also use the tool to join the tube and the surface its rising from.

Comment: thanks, but I found that's an aftermath approach. I am looking for something that can be done beforehand and that would be great.

Comment: @ambrishdhaka  Ahh.. OK.. have a play with the _Spin_ tool and see if you like that better... but that will only give you surfaces of rotation.